# Only show form if there is PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. Iv created a small php script. Basically I have a form and inside of it I have a function called show_sent:

```
        <form method="post" action="contact.php" class="formstyle">
            <h2>Formulaire de contact : </h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <?
function show_sent(){
    ?>
    <p>Sent</p>

            <?
} // the function finishes here
?>
```

.......

I was hoping that it would only show the 'Sent' text when I call that function. How could I do this?
Thanks

contact.php is the same page as the form

Comment: I guess that you want to show this message ("sent") after somebody has used the form. Then you should provide us more info about `contact.php` as it is the file you send the form to.

Comment: basically if there is stuff if (!$_POST){do_function();die();} it will do stuff incluing show the text

Comment: whats going on every answer is correct and everyone gets down voted?

Comment: Reported abuse. Whoever did it may be getting the much-unwanted attention of a Mod soon.

Comment: I've upvoted Sam and Zen to more-than offset the serial-downvoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clean up your code a bit. Jumping into and out of HTML and PHP is not a good thing.

```
<?php

  function show_sent() {
    print "<p>Sent</p>";
  }

  if ($_POST) {
    $errors = false;
    /* logic to check data */
    if (!$errors)
      show_sent();
  }

?>

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
  </form>
```

Comment: I think it's good practice to return strings from functions, instead of having functions echo directly. So I would have `<?php 
function show_sent(){
    return "Sent";
} ?>`, and then echo out the result of that: `<?php
echo "<b>".show_sent()."</b>";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if the form data is posted. You do this by going:

```
if(isset($_POST['form_element_name']))
{
    //call the show_sent function because data has been posted
    show_sent();
}
```

or

```
function show_sent(){
    if(isset($_POST['form_element_name']))
    {

    }
}
//Call the show_sent function all the time because the code inside the function checks the POST variables.
show_sent();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is post the form to its self instead of another file then you can check if the variables have data in them and if they do call your sent function. check out this link for more info on post self.
http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/51903-php-self-submitting-form.html